# переписать выражение, с помощью "строковых шаблонов"

Tags: javascript

Считаю продолжительность жизни всех учёных:

```js
const totalYears = inventors.reduce((total, inventor) => {
  return total + (inventor.passed - inventor.year);
}, 0);

alert(totalYears);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    const inventors = [{
      first: 'Albert',
      last: 'Einstein',
      year: 1879,
      passed: 1955
    }, {
      first: 'Isaac',
      last: 'Newton',
      year: 1643,
      passed: 1727
    }, {
      first: 'Galileo',
      last: 'Galilei',
      year: 1564,
      passed: 1642
    }, {
      first: 'Marie',
      last: 'Curie',
      year: 1867,
      passed: 1934
    }, {
      first: 'Johannes',
      last: 'Kepler',
      year: 1571,
      passed: 1630
    }, {
      first: 'Nicolaus',
      last: 'Copernicus',
      year: 1473,
      passed: 1543
    }, {
      first: 'Max',
      last: 'Planck',
      year: 1858,
      passed: 1947
    }, {
      first: 'Katherine',
      last: 'Blodgett',
      year: 1898,
      passed: 1979
    }, {
      first: 'Ada',
      last: 'Lovelace',
      year: 1815,
      passed: 1852
    }, {
      first: 'Sarah E.',
      last: 'Goode',
      year: 1855,
      passed: 1905
    }, {
      first: 'Lise',
      last: 'Meitner',
      year: 1878,
      passed: 1968
    }, {
      first: 'Hanna',
      last: 'Hammarström',
      year: 1829,
      passed: 1909
    }];
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

С кодом все понятно, не пойму как переписать это выражение с помощью строковым шаблонов es6:

```
return total + (inventor.passed - inventor.year);
```

Пробовал так, не получается:

```
return `${total} ${inventor.passed} - ${inventor.year}`;
```

но минус работает как символ, если я правильно понимаю?

Comment: строковые шаблоны нужны чтобы _собрать строку_. Внутри reduce ты собираешь **число**. Там нет смысла использовать строковые шаблоны

Comment: Непонятно какой результат ты хочешь получить

Comment: @Grundy, кстати да, весь вопрос то я и не прочитал =)

Comment: @Grundy okay.jpg, понятно. выходит это лишнее здесь. хотел посовременнее сделать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безотносительно самой задачи, **про использование строковых шаблонов**:

`${inventor.passed - inventor.year}`, то что внутри `${}` - это js, то что снаружи - обычная строка.

1. [Простые примеры работы со строковыми шаблонами на es6-features](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation).
2. [Строковые шаблоны на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
3. [Спецификация по строковым шаблонам](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literals).

**Еще в стрелочных функциях** очень удобно опускать фигурные скобки и `return`

```
(param, anotherParam) => {
    return param + anotherParam;
}
```

можно заменить на:
`(param, anotherParam) => param + anotherParam`

Comment: вот `forEach` как раз лишнее усложнение и использование не на своем месте.

Comment: `reduce` такой же как и `forEach` просто не имеет побочных воздействий. Да и запись с ним выглядит намного чище и без внешних переменных

Comment: В данном случае точно: `(total, inventor) => total + (inventor.passed - inventor.year)` - нет `+=` который изменяет глобальную переменную, плюс результат можно поместить в `const` а не `let` чтобы его нельзя было случайно изменить :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52062/discussion-between-grundy-and---).

Comment: (Я по прежнему не люблю reduce но Grundy убедил меня что это не относится к ответу, поэтому упоминания я удалил =))